# Regular Expression Testing

Tags: python, regex

So i have been working on this project for myself to understand regular expressions There are 6 lines of input. The first line will contain 10 character strings. The last 5 lines will contain a valid regular expression string.
For the output, each regular expression print all the character strings that are matches to the strings according to line 1; if none match then print none. # is used to say it is an empty string. I have gotten everything but the empty string part so here is my code 
and example input that would be

```
1)#,aac,acc,abc,ac,abbc,abbbc,abbbbc,aabc,accb
```

and i would like the second input to be

```
2)b*
```

the output im trying to get is #

and so far it outputs nothing

```
import re

inp = input("Search String:").upper().split(',')

for runs in range(50):
    temp = []
    query = input("Search Query:").replace("?", "[A-Z_0-9]+?+$").upper()
    for item in inp:
        search = re.match(query, item)
        if search:
            if search.group() not in temp:
                temp.append(search.group())
    if len(temp) > 0:
        print(" ".join(temp))
    else:
        print("NONE")
```

Comment: `x = print("...` could be a problem.

Comment: I like to use https://regex101.com/#python when testing a regex.  It gives you a break down of your expression which it helpful.

Comment: oh i was testing something let me remove that

Comment: Are you sure it "outputs nothing"? When I run your exact program, it outputs "NONE".

Comment: yeah but it should not output none

Comment: heres my output Search String:#,aac,acc,abc,ac,abbc,abbbc,abbbbc,aabc,accb
Search Query:b*

Search Query:

Comment: is there anything anyone knows that i can do to fix this

Comment: Your program is working correctly. Try `b+` instead of `b*`.

Comment: yeah but i want b* to work

Comment: so how would i get that input to work

Comment: It *is* working. `b*` matches the empty string, and that is what is being printed.

Comment: yeah but how would i make it print the # instead of the empty string

Comment: does anyone know lol

Answer (score 0):

b matches only the literal character 'b', so your search string will only match a sequence of zero or more b's, such as

```
b
```

or

```
bbbb
```

or

```
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb (and so on)
```

Your match string will not match anything else.

I don't know why you are using a specific letter, but I assume you intended an escape sequence, like "\b*", although that only matches transitions between types of characters, so it won't match # in this context.  If you use \W*, it will match # (not sure whether it will match the other stuff you want).

If you haven't already, check out the following resources on regular expressions, including all of the escape characters and metacharacters:

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

[Python.org 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)

Comment: I do not believe the program works correctly can you see if it does

Comment: Yeah so it should print no match and it does not